# Tabular Data Exchange Format

Tags: c#, json, xml, csv, format

Background:

I have used CSV for data exchange format in Asp.Net (C#) web application. The file usually used to do bulk upload for requests. It works fine until now and it still works.

However during researching with the cultures, we found many problems with the csv file. One of the biggest problem is the separator are being determined by the regional setting. It is happened when the user is editing the file in Ms Excel. For example, the delimiter is comma in US and semicolon in some region in Europe.

I have searched it for a while and I haven't found any silver bullet to handle such case. Now I am wonder if:

1. Are there any good way to handle separator definition in CSV file?
2. Is there any better data exchange format which is invariant culture with specification:

   - The file is plain text (not encoded file like ms excel xlsx)
   - It is invariant culture. I don't mean to handle decimal separator but at least invariant at delimiter
   - It is supported in spreadsheet applications such as Ms Excel
   - (optional) It can be read by OleDb engine

Or if any, is there a good practice to do tabular data exchange using flat file?

**Update:**

Up until now here is the summary of given solutions in pros and cons.

1. CSV (also generally used to represent delimited flat files):

   Pros:

   - Supported by many processor such as Excel and OleDb
   - Easy to read
   - Easy to manipulate using notepad

   Cons:

   - Has delimiter culture problem when editing with ms excel
   - Need to escape or handle delimiter characters
2. Xml:

   Pros:

   - Supported by many processor such as Excel and xml serializer
   - Easy to manipulate using notepad
   - Represent structural format

   Cons:

   - Need additional handling when being processed in excel
   - Using tags resulting in more content inside the xml
3. Json:

   Pros:

   - Represent structural format
   - Easy to manipulate using notepad

   Cons:

   - Not natively supported by spreadsheet processor such as excel (need to ensure)

Comment: Is this for C# or Java? Or both?

Comment: This is more for handling the data type. Both are welcome, but I hope there is a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tab as your delimiter is an easy switch, seems to be supported by most libraries to read or write, and works with Excel.

Comment: I'm also considering using TSV for a replacement. However I wonder why is CSV is more preferable than TSV? (as there are more CSV discussion over TSV)

Comment: I believe that CSV is often used as a generic term, no matter the delimiter actually used. (Or line delimiter, or the escaping, or the date format...) All the software I've used to read or write data to text files (spreadsheets, databases, statistical software, libraries, etc) are just as happy with either.

Comment: Currently this is the most promising solution which is easy and the smallest requirement needed. Will try to use it before deciding though.

Comment: I have chosen this as the accepted answer because the Tab Delimited is supported natively by excel (even need open with), can be processed using OleDb, and uniformly delimited

Answer (score 2):

A simple replacement to CSV can be [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - it is a very simple format with a lot of support on the different platforms.

The main benefit over the issues you have with CSV is that it doesn't have them - it is not culture dependent.

There are downsides to it as well, but those are shared with CSV (no data types to speak of, for example).

Comment: I haven't used JSON yet. Does it works with excel? (Will try it in a while)

Comment: @Fendy - see: http://excelramblings.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/excel-json-excel-in-one-line-of-code-on.html

Comment: I cannot open it from here. In 2-3 hours (I will change place) I will look onto it.

Answer (score 2):

XML is a much better method for data exchange than CSV.

1. The syntax rules are clear. The XML standards are laid out and agreed upon by international committees with deep experience in exchanging data. CSV is an ad hoc exchange format defined more by practice than by agreement.
2. The character set rules are clear. Unicode and its various encodings are also standardized by international committees.
3. Emitting XML from a program is very simple, and there are a substantial number of libraries that can help with the tough stuff, such as character sets.
4. Reading XML is also very simple. There are a significant number of libraries that can help with the tough stuff. Microsoft Excel and most commercial databases will read and write XML files.

Comment: I've tried to work with xml file in excel. However looks like the excel does not **natively** support xml. It asked to save as, and when I saved it seems like excel generated some code which I don't understand. Have you got some experience with it?

Comment: @Fendy - Excel _does_ handle XML quite well.

Comment: Yes, I'm still searching the good practice of doing XML in excel. Do you has good source for it?

Comment: From the MS Excel File menu, select Open ... Go to the folder containing your XML file. Select it.

Comment: And for generating XML from MS Excel - http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/map-and-unmap-xml-elements-HP010206397.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can read entire file into `string _var`, then apply `String.Split()` function to get an array specifying whatever set of separators `char` you need. Array then can be inserted in DB, or converted into `DataTable / DataView` , or `Range` objects corresponding to Excel Lib (Note: this solution relates to C# implementation)

Comment: I'm sorry but looks like this can't be done. Using this approach I must validate delimited for string such as `"hello, what are you doing"` when parsing comma separated

Comment: Then, don't use comma-separated file: specify another set of delimiters.

Comment: I will try to research with custom delimiter such as vertical bar `|`. However I'm unsure about the availability with spreadsheet processor such as excel or openOffice calc.

Comment: Yeah, it may work, but the same question as you asked in regards to comma will apply here: what if "|" is included in text? It's a conceptual issue: if delimiter is allowed to be a part of the text, then Split() could not work properly. You should either use xml instead, or restrict delimiter usage in the text.

Comment: Well in this case it should wrap the pipe (|) character in double quotes, but it need regex processing. Another thing, this type of delimited seems like does not natively supported in excel.